# Apache2 subdomain go to different folder

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, virtualhost

I want to subdomain use different folder. For example: `example.com` use `/var/www/example` and `blog.example.com` use `/var/www/exampleblog`.

Right now if I go to `example.com` or `www.example.com` the website loads correctly, but if I go to `blog.example.com` I got `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN`.

The virtualhost files:

```
example.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/example/
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
        <Directory "/var/www/example/">
                AllowOverride All
                Options FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example-error
</VirtualHost>
```

And:

```
exampleblog.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/exampleblog
        ServerName blog.example.com
        <Directory "/var/www/exampleblog/">
                AllowOverride All
                Options FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/exampleblog-error
</VirtualHost>
```

What did I incorrectly?

Comment: `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` is unrelated to Apache, it means that your `blog.example.com` name can not be resolved, check your dns settings.

Comment: My Domain DNS settings is: nakeddomain, blog and www is redirected to the same IP address (to my VPS)

Comment: If you go to https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/ and test A record for blog.example.com, does it resolve properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was: The domain registrar isn't sent out the new settings when I wrote the question. They wrote, that it will be about 15-20 minutes, but somewhy it took more time.